# Maximum value for each position in multiple lists

Tags: list-comprehension

I need to make a list comprehension consisting of the maximum values for each position. For L1, L2, and L3, I want to get `[4, 5, 3, 5]`. Here's what I've got so far:

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L2 = [4, 3, 2, 3]
L3 = [0, 5, 0, 5]

maxs = []

L4 = list(zip(L1,L2,L3))

print (maxs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following comprehension will do:

```
>>> [max(tpl) for tpl in zip(L1, L2, L3)]
[4, 5, 3, 5]
```

You can also use `map` to apply the `max` function to all the zipped tuples:

```
>>> list(map(max, zip(L1, L2, L3)))
[4, 5, 3, 5]
```